# Capistrano 3.7 new SCM declaration is throwing errors

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

Based on the Readme here https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v3.6.0/UPGRADING-3.7.md

Updating the Gemfile and running bundle install works correctly. However, 
removing the `:scm` variable from deploy.rb and adding

`require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git`

to the Capfile produces the following error:

`cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/scm/git`

Looking at the repo and the available branches, I'm not seeing any directory for /scm and subsequently no git.rb file other than in the main /lib/capistrano/ directory.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug with the current master branch?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue in a project that hasn't been updated in a while. Upgrading capistrano solved the issue.

`bundle update capistrano`